# Generics, enums and custom attributes - is it possible?

Tags: c#, generics

Apologies for the amount of code, but it is easier to explain it this way.

I have a custom attribute CustomUserData implemented as follows:

```
public class CustomUserData : Attribute
{
   public CustomUserData(object aUserData)
   {
      UserData = aUserData;
   }
   public object UserData { get; set; }
}
```

and an extension method for enums as:

```
public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static TAttribute GetAttribute<TAttribute>(this Enum aValue) where TAttribute : Attribute
    {
        Type type = aValue.GetType();
        string name = Enum.GetName(type, aValue);
        return type.GetField(name)
                   .GetCustomAttributes(false)
                   .OfType<TAttribute>()
                   .SingleOrDefault();
    }

    public static object GetCustomUserData(this Enum aValue)
    {
        CustomUserData userValue = GetAttribute<CustomUserData>(aValue);
        return userValue != null ? userValue.UserData : null;
    }
}
```

I then have a helper class that serializes/deserializes an enum that has custom data associated with it as follows:

```
public static class ParameterDisplayModeEnumListHelper
{
    public static List<ParameterDisplayModeEnum> FromDatabase(string aDisplayModeString)
    {
        //Default behaviour
        List<ParameterDisplayModeEnum> result = new List<ParameterDisplayModeEnum>();

        //Split the string list into a list of strings
        List<string> listOfDisplayModes = new List<string>(aDisplayModeString.Split(','));

        //Iterate the enum looking for matches in the list
        foreach (ParameterDisplayModeEnum displayModeEnum in Enum.GetValues(typeof (ParameterDisplayModeEnum)))
        {
            if (listOfDisplayModes.FindIndex(item => item == (string)displayModeEnum.GetCustomUserData()) >= 0)
            {
                result.Add(displayModeEnum);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static string ToDatabase(List<ParameterDisplayModeEnum> aDisplayModeList)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;

        foreach (ParameterDisplayModeEnum listItem in aDisplayModeList)
        {
            if (result != string.Empty)
                result += ",";
            result += listItem.GetCustomUserData();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

however this is **specific** to **ParameterDisplayModeEnum** and I have a bunch of enums that I need to treat this way for serialization/deserialization so I would prefer to have a generic such as:

```
public static class EnumListHelper<TEnum>
{
    public static List<TEnum> FromDatabase(string aDisplayModeString)
    {
        //Default behaviour
        List<TEnum> result = new List<TEnum>();

        //Split the string list into a list of strings
        List<string> listOfDisplayModes = new List<string>(aDisplayModeString.Split(','));

        //Iterate the enum looking for matches in the list
        foreach (TEnum displayModeEnum in Enum.GetValues(typeof (TEnum)))
        {
            if (listOfDisplayModes.FindIndex(item => item == (string)displayModeEnum.GetCustomUserData()) >= 0)
            {
                result.Add(displayModeEnum);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static string ToDatabase(List<TEnum> aDisplayModeList)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;

        foreach (TEnum listItem in aDisplayModeList)
        {
            if (result != string.Empty)
                result += ",";
            result += listItem.GetCustomUserData();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

However this will not work as GetCustomUserData() cannot be invoked. Any suggestions? I cannot change the use of the custom attribute or the use of the enums. I am looking for a generic way to do the serialization/deserialization without having to write a concrete list helper class each time.

All suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
public static class EnumListHelper
{
    private static void EnsureIsEnum<TEnum>()
    {
        if (!typeof(TEnum).IsEnum)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("The {0} type is not an enum.", typeof(TEnum)));
    }

    public static List<TEnum> FromDatabase<TEnum>(string aDisplayModeString)
        where TEnum : struct
    {
        EnsureIsEnum<TEnum>();
        //Default behaviour
        List<TEnum> result = new List<TEnum>();

        //Split the string list into a list of strings
        List<string> listOfDisplayModes = new List<string>(aDisplayModeString.Split(','));

        //Iterate the enum looking for matches in the list
        foreach (Enum displayModeEnum in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)))
        {
            if (listOfDisplayModes.FindIndex(item => item == (string)displayModeEnum.GetCustomUserData()) >= 0)
            {
                result.Add((TEnum)(object)displayModeEnum);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static string ToDatabase<TEnum>(List<TEnum> aDisplayModeList)
        where TEnum : struct
    {
        EnsureIsEnum<TEnum>();
        string result = string.Empty;

        foreach (var listItem in aDisplayModeList.OfType<Enum>())
        {
            if (result != string.Empty)
                result += ",";
            result += listItem.GetCustomUserData();
        }

        return result;
    }
}

var fromDatabase = EnumListHelper.FromDatabase<TestEnum>("test");
EnumListHelper.ToDatabase(fromDatabase);
```

**UPDATE 0**

To be clear, because we cannot restrict generics to Enum we should check that the type `TEnum` is an enum and throw an exception if it is not.
When we use the `FromDatabase` method we know that `TEnum` is enum, and we can write this code to cast an enum to the specified `TEnum`:

```
result.Add((TEnum)(object)displayModeEnum)
```

in the `ToDatabase` method we also know that `TEnum` is enum and we can write this code to convert `TEnum` to the `Enum` type:

```
aDisplayModeList.OfType<Enum>()
```

Comment: That is great and just want I was trying to achieve. Thanks.

Comment: To help with type safety as much as possible (not 100%) you could add the follwing where statement `public static class EnumListHelper where T : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible`.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you'd want to restrict TEnum to Enum but that won't work as you can not restrict generics to Enum [Microsoft](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/386194/allow-enum-as-generic-constraint-in-c)
But try following, it might do the trick...

```
if (listOfDisplayModes.FindIndex(item => 
  item == (string)(displayModeEnum as Enum).GetCustomUserData()) >= 0)
```